# Application deploys to Windows Phone 7 apps rather than xbox live

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-7, xna

When I deploy my game (which uses XNA/C#) from Visual Studio to a windows phone 7 device it goes to the applications area rather than the xbox live sub directory (if I can call it that?). I know this isn't meant to be like this because sample XNA WP7 applications deploy to the xbox live sub directory.

Comment: It is called the xbox live _hub_, not subdirectory :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your game's [WMAppManifest.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28VS.92%29.aspx) file. Make sure the `Genre` attribute under the `App` element says `Apps.Games` and not `Apps.Normal`.

Comment: This did not work for me, even after a rebuild. I'm using silverlight/xna hybrid, so is there something else needed for that setup?