# How to make an app appear in games (xbox) section of wp 7/8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have made a game(simple one, does not use xna).

I want that when installed it should appear in the games (xbox) section in windows phone 7/8.

How to do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application deploys to Windows Phone 7 apps rather than xbox live](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357820/application-deploys-to-windows-phone-7-apps-rather-than-xbox-live)

Comment: There is an answer here than matches that other question, it is unclear whether this is what the OP meant in their question.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Genre attribute of the App element in your game's manifest to "Apps.Game" and your game will show up in the Games Hub.

Comment: I believe they mean the "Xbox" section of the Games category.

Answer (score 0):

Only approved developers can make games that appear in the Xbox sub-section of the Games Hub.

For example see comments on [this Channel 9 post which talks about Xbox live for Windows 8](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-756T). (The comments refer to WP7 however).