# How to resume WP8 apps by click app icon again

Tags: windows-phone-8, resume

I am writing a C++ DirectX application without XAML for Windows Phone 8.

first I use win key or long press back key to hang the app.
and then click the icon , the app  will restart not resume.

same as
lots of games in store and the default template cube DirectX sample app.

but Gameloft's game Asphalt 7, when i click the icon, it resume the game
(it resume without loading , so I am sure that it is resumed ,it is not restated)

how can resume the apps by click icon.

and another question, how could I declare my apps as a game
(it will be listed in "XBOX GAME").
I used to think it will be declared when submitting. but when I tested a lot xap file, I find that it is declared in xap file,not a information defined in app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by implementing "fast app resume". You can read about this on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj735579(v=vs.105).aspx).

The question about game categorization has been covered before at [How to make an app appear in games (xbox) section of wp 7/8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291720/how-to-make-an-app-appear-in-games-xbox-section-of-wp-7-8).

Comment: I'v already read this yesterday.
but it says 
"Caution:
Direct3D apps do not distinguish between a fresh launch and an app relaunch. These apps always resume the previous experience. XAML and Direct3D apps as well as Direct3D with XAML apps can participate in fast resume like typical XAML apps."

does my English is too pool and misunderstanding something?

Comment: OK I find that, Direct3D is always resume the previous experience. BUT I also need to add “ActivationPolicy="Resume"' in WMAppManifest.xml.
I used to think "Fast app resume" is always enabled for D3D app, and it does not the function what I wanted. thanks.

and what about the other question?

Comment: I change Apps.Normal to Apps.Games.
When installed, it does not appear in GameHub neither in app list.
so I even can't launch the app.